# mySQL Php Update - 101

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

love this site,  I have been learning mysql and php to help me design and iPhone Messaging client (for recreational purpose, and not publishing to app store)

I am having an issue, trying to update a specific item in a table, basically I am trying to let the message be marked as read once the user reads the message, however have been getting the error

Error Message:

> Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read='MAYBE' WHERE id='19'' at line 1

Here is the URL EXAMPLE I am sending the GET from.  this should find row/id # 19 and mark READ as YES, so it has been read, previously it was set to NO.

```
 http://myawesomesite.com/markasread.php?idnumber=19&readmessage=MAYBE
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$useridnumber = $_GET['idnumber'];
$didread = $_GET['readmessage'];

$conn = mysql_connect("sqlurl.com","sqllogin","sqlpassword");
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
$sql = ("UPDATE messages SET read='$didread' WHERE id='$useridnumber'");


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

any help or clarification would be amazing, I understand having my login information on the same php and sql injections, but figured since this app is dedicated to only two people for private chatting that I would not need to really address any security concerns at this point.... :-)

Comment: Is `$useridnumber` a string or a number. I would suspect it is a number in which case you don't need the quotes around it.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around your sql statement?

Comment: What type of data is column `read`?

Comment: On another note, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: read is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), use `\`read\``

Answer (score 4):

`read` is a reserved word in mysql - docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

You will need to escape it using backticks - `. also, remove the parentheses `()` around the `$sql` as they are not necessary.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `messages` SET `read`='$didread' WHERE `id`='$useridnumber'";
```